# How to remove node from Binary Tree (Java)

Tags: java, data-structures

Heya I'm working on Binary tree and stuck on how to remove node from binary tree.I asked it from my instructor and did some googling but they wasn't helpful. My instructor said there is a 3 conditions to remove node from tree.

1.If node is leaf

2.If node has both child

3.If node has only one child

Here's code I wrote:

```
public void remove(Object theElement) {
    BinaryTreeNode currentNode = this.root;
    ArrayStack temp = new ArrayStack();
    while(currentNode != null) {
        if(currentNode.getLeftChild() == null  
               && currentNode.getRightChild() == null 
               && currentNode.getElement().equals(theElement)) {
            currentNode = null;
            break;
        }
        else if(currentNode.getLeftChild() != null
                    && currentNode.getRightChild() == null
                    && currentNode.getElement().equals(theElement)) {
            BinaryTreeNode p = currentNode;
            BinaryTreeNode c = currentNode.leftChild;
            while(c != null) {
                p = c;
                c = c.rightChild;
            }
            p.rightChild = null;
            System.out.println("Done removing node with left child");
            break;
        }
        else if(currentNode.getLeftChild() == null
                    && currentNode.getRightChild() != null
                    && currentNode.getElement().equals(theElement)) {
            BinaryTreeNode p = currentNode;
            BinaryTreeNode c = currentNode.rightChild;
            while(c != null) {
                p = c;
                c = c.rightChild;
            }
            p.rightChild = null;
            System.out.println("Done removing node with right child");
            break;
        }
        else if(currentNode.getLeftChild() != null
                    && currentNode.getRightChild() != null
                    && currentNode.getElement().equals(theElement)){
            BinaryTreeNode p = currentNode;
            BinaryTreeNode c = currentNode.rightChild;
            while(c != null) {
                p = c;
                c = c.rightChild;
            }
            p.rightChild = null;
            System.out.println("Done removing node with left and right child");
            break;
        }
        else {
            if(currentNode.getLeftChild() != null)
                temp.push(currentNode.getLeftChild());
            if(currentNode.getRightChild() != null)
                temp.push(currentNode.getRightChild());
        }
        if(!temp.empty()) {
            currentNode = (BinaryTreeNode)temp.pop();
        }
        else break;
    }
}
```

I could find the node that is to be removed, but can't remove it. Please help :)

Comment: What is `ArrayStack`?

Comment: @KnowNoTrend I was wondering the same. Apparently a container object that is included in `org.apache.commons.collections` and *heavily* used by `.edu` domains...

Comment: ArrayStack is just stack.

Comment: @Gaaki when you check whether a value is null, unless you specifically want *only* a check for null and no other falsey value, You can shorten it: `if(my_var == null)`  to this: `if(!my_var)`, or `if(my_var != null)` to this: `if(my_var)`

Comment: @Z4-tier This is Java, right? No such thing as a "falsey" value in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish the above. Once way is to use recursion. Below is an example (not tested, just to demonstrate the concept).

```
package org.test.junk;

public class BTreeNode {

protected BTreeNode right;
protected BTreeNode left;

public void add(BTreeNode node, NodePosition nodePosition) {

    switch(nodePosition) {

        case left:{this.left=node;break;}
        case right:{this.right=node;break;}

    }//switch closing

}//add closing

public void remove(NodePosition nodePosition) {

    switch(nodePosition) {

        case left:{remove(left);break;}
        case right:{remove(right);break;}

    }//switch closing

}//remove closing

public void remove(BTreeNode node) {

    if(node==null)return;

    if(node.equals(right)) {

        if(this.right!=null) {

            this.right.remove(NodePosition.right);
            this.right.remove(NodePosition.left);
            this.right=null;

        }//if closing

    }//if closing
    else if(node.equals(left)) {

        if(this.left!=null) {

            this.left.remove(NodePosition.right);
            this.left.remove(NodePosition.left);
            this.left=null;

        }//if closing

    }//else if closing
    else return;

}//remove closing

public static enum NodePosition{

    right,left;

}//enum closing

}//class closing
```

The idea is that if a parent node is called to remove its children (either left or right) will first call the child to remove all of its children recursively, conceptually.